# Riley Rebus Is Back!

Tags: rebus

Prefix + Infix + Suffix :

[image] [image] [image]

> > **TO CLARIFY :**
>
> The answer consists of only 1 word
>
> The 3 pictures each represent the prefix, infix, and suffix of the word respectively

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Unfortunately, this is not a riddle at all. It's just a rebus but if you can change the format of the pictures, that would be very helpful :D

Comment: Great rebus! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: Is this the kind of formatting that you were looking for?

Comment: Ooh! It's funny that if I didn't post that comment, there would be no riley rebuses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I admit using image search to find words which combine to form

> Innocent

The raw fixes being

> Inn - NOC (network operations center) - cent

Comment: Damn, yea that's the answer. Wished this can be more challenging but anyways, gonna accept this tomorrow :D

Comment: Thanks @KevinL, I looked at adding [s,b,t,m,l,h](https://superuser.com/a/1238557) before .jpg to resize, but perhaps 'b' makes the top two images too small.

Comment: No worries. I'm sure someone else can format the question for me :)